# Terraform aws_spot_fleet_request public_ip attribute not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, azure-public-ip, aws-ec2-instance-connect

ERROR:
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on spot_inst.tf line 82, in resource "null_resource" "spot_inst_ssh":
│   82:     host = element(aws_spot_fleet_request.spot_inst.*.public_ip,"${each.value.IMO}")
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "public_ip".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on spot_inst.tf line 82, in resource "null_resource" "spot_inst_ssh":
│   82:     host = element(aws_spot_fleet_request.spot_inst.*.public_ip,"${each.value.IMO}")
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "public_ip".
╵

---

Below is the main.tf file

---

```
locals {
      csvdata = csvdecode(file("C:\\Users\\myhome\\Desktop\\test_terraform\\IMO_TOKEN.csv"))
}
resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "spot_inst" {
      iam_fleet_role  = "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role"
      for_each = { for inst in local.csvdata : inst.IMO => inst }
      spot_price      = "0.5"
      target_capacity = 1
      wait_for_fulfillment = true        
      launch_specification {
        instance_type     = "m5a.xlarge"
        ami               = "ami-07dbhghghhfgfg"
        associate_public_ip_address = true
        key_name          = "dryrun"
        subnet_id = "subnet-059107999db020b76"
        vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0511bb4914501d1ce"]
    
        root_block_device{
          volume_size = 20
          volume_type = "gp3"
          iops = "3000"
        }
    
        tags = {
          Name = "CloudInst${each.value.TOKEN}"
          Environment = "dev"
          Group = "OPS"
        }
      }
    
      launch_specification {
        instance_type     = "m5d.xlarge"
        ami               = "ami-07dbhghghhfgfg"
        associate_public_ip_address = true
        key_name          = "dryrun"
        subnet_id = "subnet-059107999db020b76"
        vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0511bb4914501d1ce"]
        root_block_device{
          volume_size = 20
          volume_type = "gp3"
          iops = "3000"
        }
        tags = {
          Name = "CloudInst${each.value.TOKEN}"
          Environment = "dev"
          Group = "OPS"
        }
      }
    
    /*
      connection {
          type        = "ssh"
          host        = "${self.public_ip}"
          user        = "centos"
          private_key = "${file("C:\\Users\\myhome\\Desktop\\test_terraform\\dryrun.pem")}"
          timeout     = "5m"
          agent       = true
        }
    
    
      provisioner "remote-exec" {
          inline = ["/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/sh /home/centos/new_cloudinst.sh ${each.value.IMO} ${each.value.TOKEN}"]
      }
    */
}
    

resource "null_resource" "spot_inst_ssh" {
      depends_on = [aws_spot_fleet_request.spot_inst]
      for_each = { for inst in local.csvdata : inst.IMO => inst }
      connection {
        type        = "ssh"
        host = element(aws_spot_fleet_request.spot_inst.*.public_ip,"${each.value.IMO}")
        user        = "centos"
        private_key = "${file("C:\\Users\\myhome\\Desktop\\test_terraform\\dryrun.pem")}"
        timeout     = "5m"
        agent       = true
      }
      provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = ["/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/sh /home/centos/new_cloudinst.sh ${each.value.IMO} ${each.value.TOKEN}"]
      }
}
```

Comment: CSV file contents are below
IMO_TOKEN.csv
____________________
IMO,TOKEN
5004005,10494DA3
5123476,7B358279


Error I get :
__________________________________________
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on spot_inst.tf line 85, in resource "null_resource" "spot_inst_ssh":
│   85:     host = element(aws_spot_fleet_request.spot_inst.*.public_ip,0)
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "public_ip".

Comment: Please correctly format the code and provide **full** error message.

Comment: Edited the question with error and proper code

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
host = aws_spot_fleet_request.spot_inst[each.value.IMO].public_ip
```

Comment: I am getting below error after changing "host = aws_spot_fleet_request.spot_inst[each.value.IMO].public_ip"Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on spot_inst.tf line 85, in resource "null_resource" "spot_inst_ssh":
│   85:     host = aws_spot_fleet_request.spot_inst[each.value.IMO].public_ip
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_spot_fleet_request.spot_inst is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.value.IMO is "5004375"
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "public_ip".